# Does Keynote have its own 3d engine?

Tags: keynote, ui

I often use Keynote's 3D charts.
I find the rendering quality, precision of perspectives and speed to be similar to the results one would get from an actual 3D engine.

***Are these graphics produced by a basic 3D engine within Keynote, or are these complex images produced by the CoreGraphics engine?***

[image]